# How does a cookie work

Tags: linux, http, cookies, curl

I'm trying to send a post request through curl so I ran

```
curl --cookie /tmp/cookies.txt --cookie-jar /tmp/cookies.txt --data "name=value" http://www.mysite.com > post_request.txt
```

where I stored in /tmp/cookies.txt the cookie I found in my chrome's console. In the latter there were a name and a value. Is there a specific format I should use to write the cookie  parameters in /tmp/cookies.txt? (because I only put the value and it didn't work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the man page for [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) it says:

> The file format of the file to read cookies from should be plain HTTP headers or the Netscape/Mozilla cookie file format.

Looking up the mozilla format you find:

http://xiix.wordpress.com/2006/03/23/mozillafirefox-cookie-format/

```
<domain> <TRUE|FALSE> <PATH> <TRUE|FALSE> <TIMESTAMP> <NAME> <VALUE>
```

(tab delimited)

> Domain: the domain that set & can subsequently read the cookie. This
>   could include subdomains, e.g., .google.com means that
>   local.google.com, news.google.com, whatever.google.com could possibly
>   read the cookie, based on the next flag.
>
> Flag: either TRUE or FALSE, whether or not all machines under that
>   domain can read the cookie’s information.
>
> Path: the root path under the domain where the cookie is valid. If
>   this is /, the cookie is valid for the entire domain.
>
> Secure Flag: either TRUE or FALSE, whether or not a secure connection
>   (HTTPS) is required to read the cookie.
>
> Expiration Timestamp: the “Unix Time” in seconds when the cookie is
>   set to expire.
>
> Name: the name of the value that the cookie is storing/saving.
>
> Value: the value

(You could of course also just use the plain HTTP headers as stated.)